# Intro tour guide multi page plugins in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, intro.js, bootstrap-tour

I'm thinking to use angular-intro.js in my app for the introduction tour of the website. I want to use this tour through out different pages back and forth. Is there any option to go to the previous step through this plugin? All i see in multi page example is we can display the tour in different pages but we can't go to the previous step. Can some one had used any other plugins/directives that work better.Angular-bootstrap-tour/angular-ui-tour are my other options. Help appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide any code or links about what you have tried? Did you upload your app somewhere?

Comment: I'm in the initial stage where i'm trying to add the plugin, i'm looking for the best plugin advice.

Answer (score 1):

I used [bootstrap tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) plugin with my app and it works pretty well with all the options i'm looking for.